# yii2 Issue with Homepage Slider

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii2, frameworks

I have included everything to yii2, from css files to JS files.

I have checked many times, however, the slider is not appearing on homepage.

When I checked the console, I noticed this error:

> "Uncaught TypeError: $.cookie is not a function"

in fact, I have jquery.cookie.js, how could it be and how I can fix it

```
here is AppAsset.php

class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        'css/site.css',
        'css/animate.css',
        'css/bootstrap.css',
        'css/bootstrap.min.css',
        'css/custom.css',
        'css/font-awesome.css',
        'css/owl.carousel.css',
        'css/owl.theme.css',
        'css/style.blue.css',
        'css/style.default.css',
        'css/style.green.css',
        'css/style.marsala.css',
        'css/style.pink.css',
        'css/style.red.css',
        'css/style.turquoise.css',
        'css/style.violet.css',
    ];
    public $js = [
    'js/jquery.cookie.js',
    'js/waypoints.min.js',
    'js/owl.carousel.js',
    'js/jquery.parallax-1.1.3.js',
    'js/owl.carousel.min.js',
    'js/bootstrap-hover-dropdown.js',
    'js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js',
    'js/bootstrap.min.js',
    'js/front.js',
    'js/gmaps.js',
    'js/gmaps.init.js',
    'js/jquery.counterup.min.js',
    'js/respond.min.js',
    'http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js',
    'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js',
```

here is main.php

```
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\bootstrap\Nav;
use yii\bootstrap\NavBar;
use yii\widgets\Breadcrumbs;
use app\assets\AppAsset;

AppAsset::register($this);
?>
<?php $this->beginPage() ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>



    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="robots" content="all,follow">
    <meta name="googlebot" content="index,follow,snippet,archive">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Urgaz Carpet</title>

    <meta name="keywords" content="">



    <!-- Favicon and apple touch icons-->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="img/apple-touch-icon.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="img/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="img/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="img/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="img/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="img/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="img/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="img/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png" />


    <link href="css/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/owl.theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body style="padding-bottom: 0px">
<?php $this->beginBody() ?>

  <div id="all">

        <header>

            <!-- *** TOP ***
_________________________________________________________ -->
            <div id="top">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-5 contact">
                         <!--    <p class="hidden-sm hidden-xs"> --><img src="img/tel.png">  Тел.: +99898 1600066, +99895 50050962  <img style="padding-left: 30px" src="img/mail.png">  info@urgaz.uz      
                            <p class="hidden-md hidden-lg"><a href="#" data-animate-hover="pulse"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></a>  <a href="#" data-animate-hover="pulse"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-7">
                            <div class="social">
                                <a href="#" class="external facebook" data-animate-hover="pulse"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                                <a href="#" class="external gplus" data-animate-hover="pulse"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
                                <a href="#" class="external twitter" data-animate-hover="pulse"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                                <a href="#" class="email" data-animate-hover="pulse"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a>
                            </div>


                               <img style="padding-left: 30px" src="img/location.png"> Самаркандская область,г. Ургут, ул. Каратепа 25   

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


    _________________________________________________________ -->

            <div class="navbar-affixed-top" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="200">

                <div class="navbar navbar-default yamm" role="navigation" id="navbar">

                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="navbar-header">
                          <a href="index.html"><img src="img/3-1.png"  height="80px" width="80px" alt="Universal logo" class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"></a>

                            <div class="navbar-buttons">
                                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle btn-template-main" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navigation">
                                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                    <i class="fa fa-align-justify"></i>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--/.navbar-header -->

                        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navigation"  >

                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                <li class="active">
                                    <a style="height:80px !important;" href="index.html">Главная страница  </b></a>
                                                                  </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="index.html">О КОМПАНИИ  </b></a>

                                </li>
                                <li class="dropdown use-yamm yamm-fw">
                                    <a href="index.html">ПРОДУКЦИЯ  </b></a>

                                </li>


                                <li>
                                    <a href="index.html">ПРОДУКЦИЯ  </b></a>
                                 </li>
                            </ul>

                        </div>




                        <div class="collapse clearfix" id="search">

                            <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                                    <span class="input-group-btn">

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-template-main"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>

                </span>
                                </div>
                            </form>

                        </div>


                    </div>


                </div>

            </div>

            <!-- *** NAVBAR END *** -->

        </header>

        <!-- *** LOGIN MODAL ***
_________________________________________________________ -->

        <div class="modal fade" id="login-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="Login" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">

                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="Login">Customer login</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form action="customer-orders.html" method="post">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email_modal" placeholder="email">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password_modal" placeholder="password">
                            </div>

                            <p class="text-center">
                                <button class="btn btn-template-main"><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> Log in</button>
                            </p>

                        </form>



                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>




        <?= $content ?>



 <footer id="footer" style="padding-bottom: 0px !important;">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                    <h4>Наша цель</h4>

                    <p>Четкая организация технологического процесса, использование самого современного импортного оборудования в сочетании с высокой квалификацией работников</p>

                    <hr>


                    <hr class="hidden-md hidden-lg hidden-sm">

                </div>
                <!-- /.col-md-3 -->

                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">

                    <h4>Новости</h4>

                    <div class="blog-entries">
                        <div class="item same-height-row clearfix">
                            <div class="image same-height-always">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php yii::$app->homeurl;?>img/art/1.jpg" alt="">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="name same-height-always">
                                <h5><a href="#">НОВЫЕ ПАРТНЕРЫ С URGAZ CARPET</a></h5>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="item same-height-row clearfix">
                            <div class="image same-height-always">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php yii::$app->homeurl;?>img/art/4.jpg" alt="">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="name same-height-always">
                                <h5><a href="#">ГОСТЬ ПРИЕХАЛ В УРГАЗ ИЗ БУХАРЫ</a></h5>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="item same-height-row clearfix">
                            <div class="image same-height-always">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php yii::$app->homeurl;?>img/art/3.jpg" alt="">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="name same-height-always">
                                <h5><a href="#">НОВАЯ КОНФЕРЕНЦИЯ С МЕНЕДЖЕРАМИ В УРГАЗЕ</a></h5>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <hr class="hidden-md hidden-lg">

                </div>
                <!-- /.col-md-3 -->

                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">

                    <h4>контакт</h4>

                    <p><strong>"Urgaz" carpet</strong>
                        <br>ул. Каратепа 25
                        <br>г. Ургут
                        <br>Самаркандская область
                        <br>141600, Узбекистан

                    </p>

                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-small btn-template-main">Контактная страница</a>

                    <hr class="hidden-md hidden-lg hidden-sm">

                </div>
                <!-- /.col-md-3 -->



                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">

                    <h4>Новейшие ковры</h4>

                    <div class="photostream">
                        <div>
                            <a href="#">
                                <img src="<?php yii::$app->homeurl;?>img/catalog/1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="#">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <a href="#">
                                <img src="<?php yii::$app->homeurl;?>img/catalog/2.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="#">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <a href="#">
                                <img src="<?php yii::$app->homeurl;?>img/catalog/3.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="#">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <a href="#">
                                <img src="<?php yii::$app->homeurl;?>img/catalog/4.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="#">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <a href="#">
                                <img src="<?php yii::$app->homeurl;?>img/catalog/5.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="#">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <a href="#">
                                <img src="<?php yii::$app->homeurl;?>img/catalog/6.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="#">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <!-- /.col-md-3 -->
            </div>

            <!-- /.container -->
        </footer>



<?php $this->endBody() ?>
</body>
</html>
<?php $this->endPage() ?>
```

and here is site/index.php

```
 <section>
            <!-- *** HOMEPAGE CAROUSEL ***
 _________________________________________________________ -->

      <div class="home-carousel">

          <div class="dark-mask"></div>

          <div class="container">
              <div class="homepage owl-carousel">
                  <div class="item">
                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-sm-5 right">
                              <p>
                                  <!-- <img src="img/logo.png" alt=""> -->
                              </p>
                              <div class="background">
                                  <div class="transboxt">
                                      <h2 style="font-size: 22px;color: yellow"> “URGAZ CARPET” – ОДИН ИЗ ЛУЧШИХ ПРОИЗВОДИТЕЛЕЙ КОВРОВОЙ ПРОДУКЦИИ В УЗБЕКИСТАНЕ</h2>
                                  </div></div>
                              <div class="transboxt">
                                  <p style="color: white">Универсальность, оригинальные коллекции и дизайны</p></div>

                          </div>
                          <div class="col-sm-7">
                              <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php yii::$app->homeurl;?>img/slider/carpet.png" alt="">
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="item">
                      <div class="row">

                          <div class="col-sm-7 text-right">
                              <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php yii::$app->homeurl;?>img/slider/carpet2.png"   alt="">
                          </div>

                          <div class="col-sm-5">  <div class="transboxt">
                                  <h2 style="font-size: 22px;color: yellow">ШИРОКИЙ АССОРТИМЕНТ</h2></div>
                              <ul class="list-style-none">
                                  <!-- <li Универсальность, оригинальные коллекции и дизайны </li> -->
                                  <div class="transboxt">
                                      <li style="color:  white">Более 50 видов ковров и ковровых изделий</li></div>
                                  <!-- <li>Google maps, Forms, Megamenu, CSS3 Animations and much more</li> -->
                                  <!-- <li>+ 11 extra pages showing template features</li> -->
                              </ul>
                          </div>

                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="item">
                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-sm-5 right">
                              <div class="transboxt">
                                  <h2 style="font-size: 22px;color: yellow">СОБСТВЕННАЯ ДИЗАЙНЕРСКАЯ СТУДИЯ</h2> </div>
                              <ul class="list-style-none">
                                  <li> </li>
                                  <div class="transboxt">
                                      <li style="color:white">Более тысячи неповторимых дизайнов</li></div>

                              </ul>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-sm-7">
                              <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php yii::$app->homeurl;?>img/slider/carpet3.png" alt="">
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>

              </div>
              <!-- /.project owl-slider -->
          </div>
      </div>


        <section class="bar background-gray no-mb padding-big text-center-sm">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <h2 class="text-uppercase" style="color:#ffc801">о нас</h2>
                        <p class="lead mb-small" style="color: blue">«URGAZ CARPET»</p>
                        <p class="mb-small"> Произвостства ковра и ковровых изделий
                            Совместное Узбекское-Турецкое предприятие «УргГазКарпет» основанное в 2002 году, является одним
                            из ведущих производителей ковровой продукции в Республике Узбекистан.
                            Предприятие расположено в г. Ургут, Самаркандской области.</p>

                        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-template-main">Продолжать</a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
                        <img src="<?php yii::$app->homeurl;?>img/about.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" style="width: 400px;height: 250px">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
            <div class="heading text-center">
                <h3>каталог</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="row portfolio no-space">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="box-image">
                        <div class="image">
                            <img src="<?php yii::$app->homeurl;?>img/catalog/port1.jpg"  alt="" class="img-responsive">
                        </div>
                        <div class="bg"></div>
                        <div class="name">
                            <h3><a href="#">Afsona </a></h3>
                            <h3 style="color:yellow"> Model: 001  </h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="text">
                            <p class="buttons">

                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-template-transparent-primary">Посмотреть</a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.box-image -->

                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="box-image">
                        <div class="image">
                            <img src="img/catalog/port2.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                        </div>
                        <div class="bg"></div>
                        <div class="name">
                            <h3><a href="#">Afsona </a></h3>
                            <h3 style="color:yellow"> Model: 002  </h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="text">
                            <p class="buttons">

                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-template-transparent-primary">Посмотреть</a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.box-image -->

                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="box-image">
                        <div class="image">
                            <img src="img/catalog/port3.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                        </div>
                        <div class="bg"></div>
                        <div class="name">
                            <h3><a href="#">Afsona </a></h3>
                            <h3 style="color:yellow"> Model: 003  </h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="text">
                            <p class="buttons">

                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-template-transparent-primary">Посмотреть</a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.box-image -->

                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="box-image">
                        <div class="image">
                            <img src="img/catalog/port4.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                        </div>
                        <div class="bg"></div>
                        <div class="name">
                            <h3><a href="#">Afsona </a></h3>
                            <h3 style="color:yellow"> Model: 004  </h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="text">
                            <p class="buttons">

                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-template-transparent-primary">Посмотреть</a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.box-image -->
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="box-image">
                        <div class="image">
                            <img src="img/catalog/port5.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                        </div>
                        <div class="bg"></div>
                        <div class="name">
                            <h3><a href="#">Afsona </a></h3>
                            <h3 style="color:yellow"> Model: 005  </h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="text">
                            <p class="buttons">

                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-template-transparent-primary">Посмотреть</a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.box-image -->
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="box-image">
                        <div class="image">
                            <img src="img/catalog/port6.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                        </div>
                        <div class="bg"></div>
                        <div class="name">
                            <h3><a href="#">Afsona </a></h3>
                            <h3 style="color:yellow"> Model: 006  </h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="text">
                            <p class="buttons">

                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-template-transparent-primary">Посмотреть</a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.box-image -->
                </div>




            </div>

            <div class="see-more" style="padding-bottom: 50px; ">

                <a  href="#" class="btn btn-template-main" >Все каталоги</a>
            </div>


        <section class="bar background-pentagon no-mb">
            <div class="container" style="width: 100% !important;">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">



                       <center>
                        <iframe width="80%" height="600px"
                                src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/aw_T5TEcFlA">
                        </iframe>
                        </center>



                        <!-- /.owl-carousel -->

                        <!-- *** TESTIMONIALS CAROUSEL END *** -->
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <!-- /.bar -->
```

Comment: Post the code you've tried. Also, this is nothing to do with PHP or Yii as what you're describing is a client side (jquery) problem

Comment: please have a look

Comment: View-source on the page and have a look in `<head>`. I don't think it's bringing in any of your js files (like `jquery.cookie.js` and others). I can't see where it's even trying to do that in your code.

Comment: Andy, I saw view source and it is bringing cookie.js and others JS includes are also ok, maybe the problem is another? can you help me with that? and can you give me your facebook or something to check my work?

Comment: No sorry, I don't offer a free work checking service, thanks for asking though. Is the code you're using inside `document.ready`. The error is that it cannot instantiate `$.cookie` so it's either unable to reference that, or it's not firing on page load, or where it should.